# c++ inheritance, polymorphism and storing objects

Tags: c++, list, inheritance, polymorphism, storage

I was given a simple assignment which wasn't challenging at first, however gives me a headache and I can't solve one(two?) problem, which is storing objects (without slicing) and getting to the wanted functions.

I assume it is a problem of either polymorphism and virtualization, so to the point:

I have a class Vehicle:

```
class Vehicle 
{ 
protected: 
    int speed;
    int id;

public: 
    int getSpeed ();
    int getID();
};
```

and a class that inherits from it:

```
class SuperVehicle : public Vehicle
{
protected: 
    int acceleration; 

public:
    int getAcceleration();
    int getSomething();
    int setAcceleration(int number);
};
```

Now my aim is to get a list(or other type of storing) of all vehicles (including SuperVehicles), fill it randomly with either Vehicles or SuperVehicles, and then randomly 
get to the correct methods, like:

```
list<Vehicle*> listOfVehicles;
list<Vehicle*>::iterator VehiclesIterator;
for(int i = 0; i <5; i++)
{
    if (i % 2) listOfVehicles.push_back(new Vehicle());
    else listOfVehicles.push_back(new SuperVehicle());
}
while(true)
{
    randomVehicle = rand() % 5;
    for(VehiclesIterator = listOfVehicles.begin();
        VehiclesIterator != listOfVehicles.end(); VehicleIterator++)
    {
    if (VehicleIterator.getID() == randomVehicle) break;
    }
    if (randomVehicle % 2) randomFunction = rand() % 2;
    else randomFunction = rand() % 4;

    switch(randomFunction)
    {
    case 0: (*VehicleIterator)->getSpeed(); break;
    case 1: (...)
    case 2: (*VehicleIterator)->getAcceleration(); break
    case 3: (...)
    }
}
```

I don't care about the assignment. Just want to solve this, because thinking of the solution takes all my time. Appreciate all answers.

Comment: so what's your exact problem?

Comment: Virtual member functions are exactly about  "getting the right function"

Comment: This is not working, iterator is not showing methods of SuperVehicle, only those of the base class, as it is probably slicing (based on the type of iterator).

Comment: Since you want to store non related classes in a single list: have a look at boost::any

Comment: there's no need for virtual functions because there are no overridden functions in derived class

Comment: @vonbrand there is a problem with iterator, had i used virtual function, the problem would still occur: can't access methods of the derived class

Comment: @DieterLücking is it possible to solve it without using boost?

Comment: @brian Just look into the source.

Comment: I take it that "pojazd" is actually meant to say "Vehicle"? And you want to use `getSomething()` when you have a `SuperVehicle`?

Comment: If you have a `Vehicle`, you cannot call `getAcceleration` out of the blue, because `Vehicle`s have no such method. If you want want to check the type at run time and then either call `getAcceleration` or do something else, you commit a sin against object orientation and will burn in [LSP hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Please don't do that.

Comment: Again, use virtuall functions

Comment: Again - even with using a virtual function, the problem persists - one can't get to a derived class' specific method using a list of base class type.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming my comment about `pojazd` being `Vehicle`, and that the problem is accessing the additional function `getAccelleration` (etc) in the derived class `SuperVehicle`, then the solution is to either:

1. Make the base-class have a virtual function that "does nothing" in the baseclass.
2. Use `dynamic_cast` and check the result.

Example of solution 2:

```
SuperVehicle* sv = dyanmic_cast<SuperVehicle*>(*VehicleIterator);
if(sv)
{
    sv->getAcceleration();
}
else
{
    cout << "Not a supervehicle, don't try to get accelleration!" << endl;
}
```

Typically, it is frowned upon to use `dynamic_cast` (because it essentially destroys the flow of the code with a bunch of if-statements, especially when there are many derived classes). It is better to have base-classes that have empty/no-op functions and/or wrap the functionality such that the generic functionality can be maintained without casts and lots of if-statements.

Comment: To use a dynamic_cast i have to have a virtual function, so I did. I made in a base class virtual function print(); - it does nothing. However, after applying a dynamic cast (succesfully) I get error: "Debug Assertion Failed! (...) Expression: list iterator not dereferencable" (so all in all - unsuccesful).